# How do i grab the trailing url path in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to implement a JSF application, where

```
www.myapp.com/username.
```

I want to grab the /username path and use it to determine what to display to the user. 
Just like

```
facebook.com/username
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand it like this:

You're trying to use the username as an URL parameter.

Things you need to do: make a converter, a way to accept the paramet and a way to send the parameter.

Create a class that implements the Converter interface to catch the url pattern.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)

The page that needs the user object should have this:

```
f: viewParam id="username" name="username" value="#{profileBean.user}" converter="#{userConverter}"
```

I don't know the source of the url, but if you want to send it from a bean, just concat the username to the redirect ( + "?username=" + user.username) or send it as an f:param from the page.

The answer could be more complete if you deliver more info.

Comment: OP is trying to use the username as an URL path info, not as URL parameter.

Comment: So he wants to apply something like prettyfaces to modify the url?

Comment: That's one of the possible solutions, yes. Note that the OP most likely don't want to modify the URL, but just want to keep the URL as is.